# Php trouble creating object and accessing its attributes

Tags: php

I have created a game class which represents a poker game. Im trying to read it in from a db and display one of the attribute e.g NoOfPlayers but i cannot get it working. Here is the class.

```
class pokerGame {

public $GameID, $State, $BuyIn, $Ante, $NoOfPlayers; 

function __construct() {
    $GameID = $BuyIn = $Players = $Ante = 0; 
    $State = ""; 
}

function withID($newGameID) {
    $this->read($newGameID);    
}

function read($newGameID)
{
    global $conn;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE GameID = ".$newGameID." LIMIT 1";   
    $result = $conn->query($query) or die('Error getting values: '.$query); 

    $response = array();

    if ($result->num_rows == 0) { return;}

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $GameID = $row["GameID"];
    $State = $row["State"];
    $BuyIn = $row["BuyIn"];
    $Ante = $row["Ante"];
    $NoOfPlayers = $row["NoOfPlayers"];
}

function write($buyIn,$ante)
{
    global $conn;

    $query = "INSERT INTO games (BuyIn,Ante) VALUES ('$buyIn','$ante')";    

    $conn->query($query) or die('Error Inserting Values: '.$query); 

}

function getNoOfPlayers() {
     return $this->NoOfPlayers;
 }

}
```

and here is how im trying to access it.

```
  $thisPokergame = new pokerGame();
  $thisPokergame = $thisPokergame->withID("3");

  echo $thisPokergame->getNoOfPlayers();
```

Pretty sure my error is in the class as my object is NULL, i tried viewing the attributes using the get_object_vars method.

Comment: What is the actual problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getNoOfPlayers() on null.

Comment: Basically the object is null

Comment: Your `read` function doesn't return an object, it returns nothing at all, why would you overwrite your actual object with the return of it? Just change your second line to `$thisPokergame->withID("3");`

Comment: class variables require `$this` for reference.  e.g. `$this->noPlayers = 2`

Comment: yes i see that now i actually had it right earlier but changed it. my object isnt null anymore but the values are empty, it doesnt seem to be reading from the db correctly

Comment: Progrock i tried that now getting error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) .....

Comment: never mind syntax error on my behalf. looks like im making progress now thanks guys

Comment: where does the gameid ever get put into the database so that you can read it later?

Comment: it gets put in as an autoincrement primary key field when user creates a game giving ante and buyin as parameters

Comment: You should not be using `global` in a class method. Pass the connection to the constructor and keep it as a class property, then reference it as `$this->conn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your not accessing member variables properly so your noOfPlayers is never being set.
 change

```
$NoOfPlayers = $row["NoOfPlayers"];
```

to this.

```
 $this->NoOfPlayers = $row["NoOfPlayers"];
```

and do that for all of your member variable calls